# how to install +nightly (whatever that means) so I can run cargo expand

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I don't want to use anything but the stable toolchain for my normal work but would like to be able to debug my macros using expand. I don't even now how to use anything but the default stable tool chain.

Comment: All explained in the [How Rust is Made and “Nightly Rust”](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-07-nightly-rust.html) appendix to The Rust Programming Language.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can install nightly rust with `rustup toolchain install nightly`, then you can run `cargo` as nightly with `rustup run nightly cargo [...more arguments here]` or `cargo +nightly [...more arguments here]`. If you want your normal `cargo` command to be replaced with nightly as well then you can run `rustup default nightly`.